# How to display commit signature information in Magit Rev mode when visiting a commit?

Tags: magit, command-line-arguments

Magit displays signature information in the `magit-revision` buffer when visiting a tag, but I can't seem to configure this behaviour when visiting a commit using the default bindings for `magit-visit-commit` (`<Return>` or `<Space>`). I can see the flag for visiting a commit through the `magit-diff` transient prefix, though, so I know it's *possible* for this to be configured through `magit-diff` invocation of `magit-visit-commit`, but those configurations don't seem to be available from the `<Return>` invocation. Is there something I can add to my `init.el` to make this behaviour possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No direct parity with tags

For tags, the signature displayed at the top of the section is different than the one displayed by the configurable flag `--show-signature`. The tag behavior is driven by `magit-insert-revision-tag`, which uses `git verify-tag` under the hood and so is tag specific as you've encountered. It may be that similar support should be added for `git verify-commit`, but as far as I can see that isn't available! So, no direct solution for commits.

### An alternative solution

I don't know the difference between `git verify-*` and the output given with `--show-signature`, but if `--show-signature` provides what you want, then you can change the default diff args for `magit-revision-mode` to include `--show-signature`. The following would work:

```
;; Add --show-signature to diff args for all revision-mode buffers
(put 'magit-revision-mode 'magit-diff-default-arguments
     `("--show-signature" ,@(get 'magit-diff-mode 'magit-diff-default-arguments)))
```

**Some notes on this solution:**

1. This changes the behavior of all `magit-revision-mode` buffers. I specifically targeted that mode and not `magit-diff-mode` as it was more of a local change.
2. On tags, you will two signatures since the signature at the top is generated separately.